# SQL: creating multiple INSERT statements from a result set

Tags: sql

I have a SELECT statement that picks a subset of field devices. I need to insert new records into another table , one for each member of this subset. Can you iterate the results of the SELECT clause to create multiple INSERT INTO statements, all within SQL?  Or do I need to create an application for this task?

So if this query :

```
select name from my_pets
```

returns records for 'pete', 'jack' and 'max', can I continue in SQL:

```
insert into zoo-table values('pete',x,y,z)
insert into zoo-table values('jack',a,b,c)
insert into zoo-table values('max',d,e,f)
```

Seems like there should be a method but I'm far from an SQL master.

thanks...

Comment: Where do `x`, `y`, `z`, etc. come from?

Comment: attributes for each 'pet' selected from another table (in another database)...

Answer (score 3):

insert into select

```
INSERT INTO zoo-table 
    (name, field2, field3, field4)
SELECT name, x, y, z
FROM my_pets;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: But what is the syntax for multiple `INSERT` statements?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: that will insert as many rows as the `select` returns

Comment: An alternate method would be to cycle through your results using a cursor.  You could then run as many inserts statements as you want on the data from each row from your select.  (Cursors can be expensive/slow, though.)